# Add {Sharepoint.LoginName} to query string in URL in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

This is really very simple.  I want to create a link [https://SomeOtherServer.com/subsite/appPage.aspx?Username=SharepointUserName] on a sharepoint 2010 aspx page.

I've tried with javascript, and had to load 5 JS files, and it's still barfing at new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl)

My other option would be to write a web part called UrlAppender and do it server side.

But this all seems ridiculous to me.  There must be a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding those 5 file references, you make use of `jQuery` and the excellent `SPServices` library to get the data about the current user.

Add the following files references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
```

After that, you can use the `SPGetCurrentUser` method to get data as below:

```
var thisUsersValues = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldNames: ["ID", "Name", "Account", "Work e-mail"],
    debug: false
});

var accountName = thisUsersValues[2];

var title = thisUsersValues[1];

var email = thisUsersValues[3];
```

reference - [SPGetCurrentUser](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPGetCurrentUser.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to the current user, right?

Even though there is nothing wrong with option to create a server side component( control, web part, something else) i would recommend client side approach.

[1.SharePoint 2010 CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537247(v%3Doffice.14))

In most cases there is no need to explicitly load SharePoint JS libraries, [`SP.SOD.executeFunc` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff409592(v%3Doffice.14)) should do the trick:

> Ensures that the specified file that contains the specified function
>   is loaded and then runs the specified callback function.

In your case `sp.js` library needs to loaded:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", () => {
   //sp.js has been loaded..  
});
```

Example

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", () => {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
    var currentUser = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
    ctx.load(currentUser);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
       var link = `https://SomeOtherServer.com/subsite/appPage.aspx?Username=${currentUser.get_loginName()}`; 
       console.log(link);
    }, 
    function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());    
     });
});
```

[2.SharePoint 2010 REST Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff521587(v%3Doffice.14))

Another option to consider where there is no any dependency to SharePoint libraries.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve user details by *user Id* property (in SharePoint 2010 a so called context info object is generated `_spPageContextInfo` per every page and `_spPageContextInfo.userId` returns current user id)

```
var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList(${_spPageContextInfo.userId})`;    
fetch(url, {
     method: 'GET', 
     headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
     },
     credentials: 'same-origin'
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then( data =>{
   var link = `https://SomeOtherServer.com/subsite/appPage.aspx?Username=${data.d.UserName}`; 
   console.log(link);
})
.catch(err =>{
  console.log(err);
});
```